# How can I set up a high speed connection between two Windows computers to transfer large files?

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, file-transfer

I want to be able to send folders ranging from 10 to 50 GBs from a Windows 10 computer to a Windows 7 computer. Both are connected to the same modem/router with Cat6 cables. I tried using the Windows Homegroup, the Folder Sharing option in windows and I tried using a local FTP server hosted on the W10 computer. In all of these cases, my max transference speed was 2 MB/s, which is also my current download speed from my ISP. Is there another option that gives me a greater speed than the 2 MB/s I'm stuck at?

**Additional**: It is not possible to connect the computers directly through cable. Also, I have little to no experience and knowledge in networks, even local ones. I had to use several tutorials to be able to finally set up a local FTP server.

Comment: Can you share the internal IP addresses of the two computers (192.x.x.x) and post the result of a tracert from one to the other?

Comment: What's the make / model of the device in question? Please add it to your post.

Comment: David, the internal IP of the W10 computer is 192.168.0.17 and the IP of the W7 computer is 192.168.0.20. 

Edited because the comment was confusing. The tracert gave the following results: `1- <1ms <1ms <1ms Douglas-PC [192.168.0.20]`.

I hope that I got the comment right this time.

Comment: Tim, one is a personalized desktop, so it doesn't have a make/model but for the individual components. The other is a ASUS 450x laptop with all the original hardware but the HDD, which is now a Seagate ST100LM048.

Comment: Enabling file sharing on both devices should be enough this will allow you to use SMBv3 and go through your intranet network

Comment: You should look at [Resilio](https://www.resilio.com/individuals/#plans) (formerly Bittorrent Sync). Despite the up selling on the linked page regarding "plans", for basic transfers between devices, the free version of the software should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way of making this happen:
1. Power both systems off
2. Remove hard drive from either system
3. Install said hard drive in other system (it will need power and SATA connect)
4. Because both are NTFS, the OS will pick up the new drive and assign a letter
5. Copy the files over
6. Enjoy up to 6 Gbit/s transfer speed.

Barring that, put one of the drives in a usb external drive closure, and enjoy slightly slower, but still fast, transfer speed.

Also, picking up a 64 gigabyte USB stick is also an option.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Both your options seem fine.. I question whether your router perhaps only has 100 Mbit ports rather than 1000 Mbit ports? Look at the specs for your router.. if it's only 100Mbit you are limited to only 12.5MB/s best case scenario (overheads processing and network headers will mean it'll be significantly less).

If it turns out your router is bad at switching traffic you could just get a gigabit (1000 mbit) switch and plug both computers into that and then use another cable to plug that to your router.. this will speed up PC to PC connectivity.

Even if the ports are gigabit your router may also just not be performant enough to switch an appropriate amount of traffic while also managing your ISP connection and routing.